# How to add the vertical pipes we see in Examples feature of the Scenario Outline in SpecFlow

Tags: specflow, web-api-testing

I would like to add the vertical pipes so that I can have my data table down there under "Examples" feature in Specflow. Anyone to give me any tip so I can go through it?.  My scenario outline looks like:

```
 @mytag  
   Scenario Outline: Check Noun Words

   Given Access the AnalyzeStateless URL

    And  language code
    And content of <Sentence>
    And the Expected KeyWord <Expected KeyWords>
    And the Expected Family ID <Expected FID>
    And the index <Index>
    When return the XML response
    Then the keyword should contain <FamilyID>



Examples: 
    | Index  | Sentence  | Expected KeyWords | Expected FID |
    |   1    | I need a personal credit card | personal | 92289  |
```

The "Examples" feature has been manually entered in above case. I have a thousand of rows on an excel file, any appropriate way to get all of the values  in one go?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give some code from your attempts?

Comment: Thanks @Geshode;   The "Examples" feature shoulld look like:                                                                         | Index | Sentence         |                Expected KeyWords | Expected FID |
|   1    | I need a personal credit card      |        personal     |         92289  |     And this I have entered manually. I have more than 1000 data in my data table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Specflow.Excel](http://specflow.org/plus/excel/getting-started/) which allows you to keep your examples in your excel files?